# session in java and jsp sometimes doesn't work

Tags: java, jsp, session, crystal-reports

I have a problem when set attribute with session, when I run the code have set attribute function, sometimes when I run again, that's not work. the code run going well but the code run going well again when I clear the cache. is it the attribute session value replace or not? I already try session invalidate is not work, I try remove attribute is not working too. how to fix this problem?
my code java1:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String report_name = "modules/kepesertaan/gaji/DaftarDataTarDiDataGajiInstansi.rpt";
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();

    // get value parameter from url
    String PKDCABANG = request.getParameter("PKDCABANG");
    String PKELSSBP = request.getParameter("PKELSSBP");
    String PKDSSBP = request.getParameter("PKDSSBP");
    String PBLTHGAJI = request.getParameter("PBLTHGAJI");
    String ID = request.getParameter("ID"); // ID User Login

    session.removeAttribute("report_name");
    session.removeAttribute("ID");
    session.removeAttribute("PKDCABANG");
    session.removeAttribute("PKDSSBP");
    session.removeAttribute("PKELSSBP");
    session.removeAttribute("PBLTHGAJI");

    try {
        // send value param1 dan param2 to jsp 
        session.setAttribute("report_name", report_name);
        session.setAttribute("ID", ID);
        session.setAttribute("PKDCABANG", PKDCABANG);
        session.setAttribute("PKELSSBP", PKELSSBP);
        session.setAttribute("PKDSSBP", PKDSSBP);
        session.setAttribute("PBLTHGAJI", PBLTHGAJI);

        // send request and to jsp file
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/CrystalReport-viewer.jsp").forward(request, response);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+e);
        session.invalidate(); 
    }
}
```

java2:

the code have same attribute session with java1.

jsp:

```
<%
    String report_name = (String) session.getAttribute("report_name");

    String ID = (String) session.getAttribute("ID");
    String P_KDCABANG = (String) session.getAttribute("P_KDCABANG");
    String P_KDSSBP = (String) session.getAttribute("P_KDSSBP");
    String P_BLTHGAJI = (String) session.getAttribute("P_BLTHGAJI");
    String P_KELSSBP = (String) session.getAttribute("P_KELSSBP");

    String PKDCABANG = (String) session.getAttribute("PKDCABANG");
    String PKELSSBP = (String) session.getAttribute("PKELSSBP");
    String PKDSSBP = (String) session.getAttribute("PKDSSBP");
    String PBLTHGAJI = (String) session.getAttribute("PBLTHGAJI");

    ReportClientDocument reportClientDoc = new ReportClientDocument();
    reportClientDoc.open(report_name, OpenReportOptions._openAsReadOnly);
    ParameterFieldController parameterFieldController = reportClientDoc
    .getDataDefController().getParameterFieldController();

    try{
        if (param1 != null){
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "param1", param1);
        }
        if (param2 != null){
        parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "param2", param2);
        }
        if (V_PANGKAT != null){
        parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "V_PANGKAT", V_PANGKAT);
        }

        if (ID != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "ID", ID);
        }
        if (P_KDCABANG != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "P_KDCABANG", P_KDCABANG);
        }
        if (P_KDSSBP != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "P_KDSSBP", P_KDSSBP);
        }
        if (P_BLTHGAJI != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "P_BLTHGAJI", 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(P_BLTHGAJI));
        }
        if (P_KELSSBP != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "P_KELSSBP", P_KELSSBP);
        }

        if (PKDCABANG != null) {
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "PKDCABANG", PKDCABANG);
        }
        if (PKDSSBP != null){
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "PKDSSBP", PKDSSBP);
        }
        if (PKELSSBP != null){
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "PKELSSBP", PKELSSBP);
        }
        if (PBLTHGAJI != null){
            parameterFieldController.setCurrentValue("", "PBLTHGAJI", 
                    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(PBLTHGAJI));
        }       
    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Errors: "+e);
    }

    CrystalReportViewer crystalReportPageViewer = new CrystalReportViewer();
    IReportSource reportSource = reportClientDoc.getReportSource();
    crystalReportPageViewer.setReportSource(reportSource);
    crystalReportPageViewer.setOwnPage(true);
    crystalReportPageViewer.processHttpRequest(request, response,
            application, null); 
%>
```

I tried the java1 code and run going well, then I run the java2 code and no problem, but when I run again java1, is not work. in my case, I create the crystal reports, and the parameter not sent. the error show this:

> The field was not found.---- Error code:-2147213310 Error code
>   name:fieldNotFound

How to fix this problem? the session set attribute sometimes doesn't work.

Comment: wowzer... that's some really nasty code there. JSPs? Scriptlets? Using  the session for request attributes? Yuck!

Comment: oh.. if that's nasty code, how to repair this code? have you idea for restructure? I want send parameter to crystal reports with java. and where code it's most nasty? I have no idea and any solution for my case? thanks

Comment: Where do I start?? Your business logic and view logic are jumbled together. Have a read up on [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). I suggest you use an MVC framework (eg jersey or spring MVC etc). You should NEVER need a scriptlet `<% ... %>` in JSP and this logic should be moved to the controller. Ideally, you shouldn't be using JSP at all and should use something like [freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) instead. Also, you should NEVER use the session to store request scoped data

Comment: okay. is it posibble run crystal reports viewer in java without jsp? because I need open the crystal reports, and I just know use jsp for run crystal reports viewer and crystal reports viewer use jsp code. so, in my case I use jsp and java

Comment: Never used Crystal Reports but I assume it can run outside of a Web context? Surely under the hood there's an api which uses OutputStream? I'm guessing there's a jsp wrapper which calls this API under the hood?

Comment: jsp have a viewer library so, when I want see the crystal reports in web, usually use jsp.

Comment: I'd be surprised if in 2017 anyone was forcing you to use a jsp... if they are it's time to choose a different product!! I'm guessing they are providing a jsp for legacy systems. But new products should invoke the underlying APIs (eg in a spring/jersey controller)